# RxJava adjust backpressure avoiding observeOn buffer

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

In the code below I would like the subscriber to control when the Flowable emits an event by holding a reference to the Subscription inside subscribe() and requesting the number of elements I want to be produced.

What I am experiencing is that observeOn()'s buffer with size 2 is hiding my call to subscription.request(3) as the producer is producing 2 elements at a time instead of 3.

```
public class FlowableExamples {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    long start = new Date().getTime();

    Flowable<Integer> flowable = Flowable
        .generate(() -> 0, (Integer state, Emitter<Integer> emitter) -> {
          int newValue = state + 1;
          log("Producing: " + newValue);
          emitter.onNext(newValue);
          return newValue;
        })
        .take(30);

    flowable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false, 2)
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
          Subscription subscription;

          @Override
          public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscription;
            subscription.request(5);
          }

          @Override
          public void onNext(Integer integer) {

            log("\t\treceived: " + integer);

            if (integer >= 5) {
              sleep(500);
              log("Requesting 3 should produce 3, but actually produced 2");
              subscription.request(3);
              sleep(1000);
            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onError(Throwable throwable) {}

          @Override
          public void onComplete() {
            log("Subscription Completed!!!!!!!!");
          }
        });

    sleep(40_000);
    System.out.println("Exit main after: " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + " ms");
  }

  private static void log(String msg) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + msg);
  }

  private static void sleep(long ms) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
  }
}
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why isn't `.take()` operator enough?

Comment: I would like to programmatically control the producer rate. `.take()` will only limit the number of elements accepted before completing the flow.  To my understanding the Subscription `.request(3)` should produce 3 values before calling `.request(3)` again due the slow consumer (`.sleep(500)`), but the buffer size of 2 in the `.observeOn()` mandates the whole process.